# I can't find my resource and texture pack on minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't find my resource and texture pack on minecraft. I've tried everything but it doesn't work at all. I really want to add mods and different resource and texture packs but I can't because of this.

[image: it only has this please help]

Comment: Any chance you could include a link to the full size version of that image?

Comment: did it hope it's better now.

Comment: I don't think there's anything particularly special about the resourcepacks folder - if it doesn't exist you can just create it manually yourself. Once done, just drop the zipped files in and it should become available in-game.

Answer (score 2):

It should work if you simply create a folder called resourcepacks

Answer (score -1):

Did you try...

- Reinstalling Minecraft?
- Deleting and reinstalling your .minecraft folder at https://minecraft.net?